# How to require a js library with dependencies on webpack?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack

I'm working on a Symfony 3 project and trying to build a skeleton fỏ frontend development. I decided to use [webpack encore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@symfony/webpack-encore). 
This is my webpack entry file:

```
// assets/js/app.js

// loads the jquery package from node_modules
var $ = require('jquery');
require('node-waves');
require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
require('mdbootstrap');
require('slick-carousel');
require('jquery-validation');
require('jquery-validation-unobtrusive');
require('multi-step-form-js');

$(document).ready(function() {});
```

The things seem okay if I don't use the "multi-step-form-js". If I require it into the entry file. I will get an error like this in console of Google Chrome "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined". It locates me to this snippet of code inside the libary:

```
$.validator.prototype.subset = function(container) {
    var ok = true;
    var self = this;
    $(container).find(':input').each(function() {
        if (!self.element($(this))) ok = false;
    });
    return ok;
};
```

I think the problem is missing of dependence (the "jquery-validation"). I tried to require it with this line of code "require('jquery-validation');". The problem isn't be solved. I guess that webpack use requirejs by by default so I have to find a special way to require it. Unluckily, I'm still finding. 
Are there any ideas about how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For missing dependencies, you can try installing it manually into your `devDependencies` with the following.

`npm install -D jquery-validation` or `yarn add -D jquery-validation`

Please ensure that the package name is correct. I am just using what you have spelt.

Comment: still get the same issue. I tried to debug can can see like the webpack use the requirejs. I might need the other way to require it, right? I don't know about the syntax. Trying to search for solutions.